# Hindi Typing Tutor application

Tags: software-recommendation

I have been trying to learn hindi typing which uses Devanagari script.  Do we know if there are any typing tutor applications for Hindi language (देवनागरी लिपि)?  The standard official script adopted by Indian govt. for administrative purposes is "inscript".  There are different varients of Hindi keyboard layout, but I am specifically looking for the "inscript" layout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know that [Klavaro](http://klavaro.sourceforge.net/en/) claims to be language- and layout-agnostic. It starts with teaching you the home row and branches out, teaching you groups of keys at a time. You can also supply texts to use as practice. I don't know how good it is with non-European languages in practice, but it's free and available in the Software Centre, so you could give it a go.

Comment: does not have hindi!

Comment: not even marathi!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the link where we can download the typing tutor but so far I am unable to download it as it gets timed out.

http://pune.cdac.in/html/gist/down/key.asp

Comment: link is working but the program is for windows only and is not working through wine

Comment: This seems to be obsoleted by your other answer which provides more details.  At the time, editing your existing answer to update it would have been preferred, but now you should probably just delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thing I discovered over a period of time.  We can download the hindi typing tutor from http://pune.cdac.in/html/gist/down/key.asp

[CDAC](http://pune.cdac.in/html/gist/down/key.asp) have designed it to work in DOS.  In Ubuntu we have an application known as DOSBOX.  This is basically a windows DOS emulator.  After installing this application, we can practice hindi typing in Ubuntu.  All it requires is the learning of basics of DOSBOX to run the .exe files.

Comment: link doesn't work. try searching for GIST CDAC